# Getting thirsty often even consuming water often- why?

Tags: water, body-temperature, hydration, heat, dry-mouth

I am getting thirsty often even consuming water often, more than 5 liters per day. Still I feel thirsty when I did not consuming water. Also I feel dry in my head always. I think it was the outcome of over heat in my body but I want to know the  correct reason for this.

Comment: No one on the internet can answer your question. Only a doctor who can examine you and run tests can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: From [your latest question](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/11595/effect-of-water-consumption-on-rate-of-digestion), it looks like you still may not have seen a doctor yet. Why not go see a doctor? Is it because of the cost?

Comment: I have seen doctor and doctor told me that consuming water often didn't harm my health..

Answer (score 0):

## It might be diabetes

As others have said, it might be diabetes, or it might be something else. You may need some lab tests done.

## Untreated diabetes can cause worse problems

If you do have diabetes, and you don't treat it properly, it can cause worse problems. Therefore, you should phone a doctor today and book an appointment.

## If you can't afford to see a doctor

If you can't afford to see a doctor, seek [charity care](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charity_care).

Some diabetes treatments cost more; some cost less. The expensive ones may be the best and most convenient. But, if you can't afford them, ask the doctor for cheaper treatments.

Comment: I don't have diabetes..I checked with doctor